# Press an item of a listView and check the checkbox, unchecking the previous one

Tags: android, listview, checkbox

In my app i've a listview and the items are Linearlayouts, i need a method that evrytime i press a linearLayout of my listView the CheckBox results checked and if there was a previous one unchek the previous one

This is an example of my app

[image]

And this is my code that i've put in the activity but it doesn't work

```java
private void setAscoltatoreLista() {

    Log.d(TAG, "setAscoltatoreLista()");

    list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            CheckBox box = (CheckBox) adapter.getItem(position);
            adapter.setOtherBoxesFalse();
            box.setChecked(true);

        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

kotlin version of answer:

```
list.onItemClickListener =
            OnItemClickListener { parent, view, position, id ->
                (parent as ViewGroup).children.forEach { child ->
                    val box = (view as ViewGroup)[0] as CheckBox
                    box.isChecked = true
                }

                val box = (view as ViewGroup)[0] as CheckBox
                box.isChecked = true
            }
```

There might be some reference issues. instead of forEach, use for loop, and get child with index.
But, why you don't use recyclerview. It is better by performance and flexibility.